# how do I create an Instance with this class?

Tags: java

How do I create an instance of this class to test my functions in my main program? I am trying to construct a Binary Search Tree by inserting, removing, and checking if the values are present or not. I am trying to create my object using my constructor. Each time I create an object using my constructor and I pass in the value to my constructor in my main program, I am always getting the value of the constructor which is 9 in this case as my result. I am not surprised by this. But the challenge I am facing is to use the object bst to call function insert (bst.insert()) so that it prints to appropriate result to the screen. Any help is appreciated. Below is the code:

```
class BST {
    static class Algo_BST {
        public int value;
        public Algo_BST left;
        public Algo_BST right;
        
        public Algo_BST(int value) {
          this.value = value;
        }

        public Algo_BST insert(int value) {
          // Write your code here.
                if(value < this.value){
                    if(left == null){
                         Algo_BST bst = new Algo_BST(value);
                         left = bst;
                        //this.left = new Algo_BST(value);
                    }else{
                        left.insert(value);
                    }
                }else{
                        if(right == null){
                            Algo_BST bst = new Algo_BST(value);
                             right = bst;
                            //this.right = new Algo_BST(value);
                        }else{
                            right.insert(value);
                        }
                    }
          // Do not edit the return statement of this method.
          return this;
        }

        public boolean contains(int value) {
                if (this.value < value){
                    if(left == null){
                     return false;
                    }else{
                    return left.contains(value);
                    }
                }else if(this.value > value){
                     if(right == null){
                         return false;
                     }else{
                         return right.contains(value);
                     }
                }else{
                    return true;
                }           
        }
  
       public String toString() {
            return "Data: " + this.value;
        }
       
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        BST.Algo_BST bst = new BST.Algo_BST();
        System.out.print("Insert: "+bst.insert(90));
        System.out.print("Insert: "+bst.insert(50));
        System.out.print("Insert: "+bst.insert(70));
        System.out.print("Insert: "+bst.insert(80));
        System.out.print("Contains: "+bst.contains(80));
        System.out.print("Contains: "+bst.contains(1000));
    }
}
```

Comment: The first constructor of the class Algo_BST is not valid. You're setting this.value to an undefined variable.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ - Since `int value` is a member,  it is initialized to zero, and then `this.value = value` copies it to itself.  To the OP: what exactly does "not working" mean?

Comment: Why the inner static class? Seems overly complicated.

Comment: @Robert - it's not unreasonable to have two classes for this: one for the implementation of the tree, and another to hold a main program with which to test that implementation.   I would have written two top-level classes, but in practice here it makes little difference.

Comment: @Matteo NNZ how do I make the first constructor valid? I want to create a constructor with no parameter that will take the value of the BST and will initialize or set it to whatever value I call using my functions. For instance, when I call the function/method bst.insert(90)) in my main program, it should insert 90 into the Binary Search Tree.

Comment: @iggy For instance, when I try to insert the values 90, 50, 70, and 80 into my BST, instead of getting the actual values. I am getting 0 as my output. I also have issues with my contains function as well. For instance, I tried to check if 80 is present in my BST. The answer it returns supposed to be true. It instead gave me false. This may be due to the fact that my Insert function is not working as it should that is why. I need some help in fixing this.

Comment: Your 'insert' method always returns the root, which always has the value 0, which is the only thing that gets printed.

What do you actually expect 'insert' to return to the main program?  Why is it  useful to print only one node?

Comment: @iggy I do not want to print only one node. I want to print all the nodes I passed when I called my insert method in my main function. The function insert should insert whatever nodes value I passed inside

Comment: @Robert I want to use inner static class. I want to challenge myself as I am learning Data Structures

Comment: (1) You print "root.toString()" and that is only one node.  If you intend to print the entire tree, you need to write code that traverses the whole tree, printing each node.  (2) perhaps you merely intend to print the recently-inserted node?  In which case, your insert routine needs to return that node; right now it is only capable of returning the root.  The return values of the recursive calls are ignored.  (3)  Insert is as far as I can tell correct. It's just that you have written no way to observe that.

Comment: I wrote an answer that addresses my point (2).

Answer (score 0):

I tested your class and saw some details:

First. The local property is ok in method `insert`, you do not need the extra lines:

```
//Algo_BST bst = new Algo_BST(value);
//left = bst;
this.left = new Algo_BST(value);
...
//Algo_BST bst = new Algo_BST(value);
//right = bst;
this.right = new Algo_BST(value);
```

Second. Greater than and less than validations are wrong in method `contains`:

```
// if (this.value < value){ // Wrong validation
if (this.value > value){
...
// }else if(this.value > value){ // Wrong validation
} else if(this.value < value){
```

I’ve tested the app with these fixes and it worked well.

Comment: Thank you! the contains method is working properly. However, I need some help with my constructor and create the instance of the object in my main method. I do not know why my method insert is not inserting any items in my binary search tree. It is instead initializing it to 0 instead of 90, 50, 70..etc

Comment: As I see, your constructor is not the properly one: `BST.Algo_BST bst = new BST.Algo_BST();`, you should start wiht a constructor like: `BST.Algo_BST bst = new BST.Algo_BST(12);` you need to set the root of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

These changes to `insert` make it return the newly-inserted node.  I have not tested them.

```
    public Algo_BST insert(int value) {
      // Write your code here.
            if (value < this.value) {
                if (left == null) {
                     left = new Algo_BST(value);
                } else {
                     left.insert(value)   
                }
                return left;
             } else {
                if (right == null) {
                    this.right = new Algo_BST(value);
                } else {
                    right.insert(value);
                }
                return right;
             }
      // Do not edit the return statement of this method.
      return this;
    }
```

With this change, your 'print' of the result should print what was added.  I don't see that is particularly useful since it does not show the tree structure (i.e., you could get that all wrong and the printout would still be correct).

As originally written, this tree allows repeat values. Is that intended?

Comment: Yes, it was intentional! I want it to print out repeated values. However, I am opened to suggestions that will enable me to eliminate duplicate values and how to improve this code.